# Proving the weak topology coincides with the original topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $F$ be a family of real valued continuous functions on topological space $(X,J)$.

If for each closed set $C$ in $(X,J)$, and each $x\notin C$, there exists $f\in F$ such that $f(x)=1$ and $f\equiv 0$ on $C$.

Prove that the weak topology generated by $F$ is $J$

Comment: What are your ideas on this problem, do you know what you have to show precisely?

Comment: I tried to approach the problem by proving every set in F is in J and vice versa, but I can't seem to find any ways to apply the assumption...

Comment: $F$ is a family of functions, not of sets, so that statement is ill phrased. You want to show that the weak topology given by $F$ coincides by $J$. So what is the definition of the weak topology given by the family $F$?

Comment: The weakest topology containing preimage sets of open sets in R under functions in F?... I think the 'weakest topology' part can be utilized in the proof but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J_w$ be the weak topology given by $F$, so it is the weakest topology containing $f^{-1}(U)$ for all open $U\subseteq\mathbb R$ and all $f\in F$. First check that $J$ does indeed contain all those sets.

Let $f\colon X\to \mathbb R$ be any function in $F$ and $U\subseteq \mathbb R$ an arbitrary open set. We have to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is in $J$. This is obvious, do you know why?

The interesting part is the converse, every $U\subseteq X$ with $U\in J$ is also in $J_w$. So let $U$ be an arbitary $J$-open set in $X$, then $C=X\setminus U$ is $J$-closed. Hence for every $x\in U$ there is some $f_x\in F$ such that $f_x(x)=1$ and $f_x(y)=0$ for all $y\in C$. Now you have to use this subfamily $(f_x)_{x\in U}$ of $F$ to show that $U$ is in fact $J_w$-open. Can you do this?